# c# bindingsource filter by datetime

Tags: c#, date, datetime, filter, bindingsource

The problem I'm having is that the filter will not accept the time part of a datetime.

For clarity,

This works.

```
" AND NextWorkDate <= #" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("dd.M.yyyy") + "#"
```

This doesnt work.

```
" AND NextWorkDate <= #" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("dd.M.yyyy H:mm:ss") + "#"
```

Whenever I try to include the time aspect of the datetime, the filter just doesnt work, it returns no rows.

I've tried it a thousand different ways and I really cant figure out why it won't take the damn time.

The datasource column that the filter is comparing to is a datetime with the format dd.M.yyyy H:mm:ss.

The database column is formatted completely differently, as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:fff

Could this be causing some problem along the line? I think it isn't because the filter is applied to the datasource, not the database.

Comment: Instead half the code implementation; a more complete example would be helpful.

Comment: Try: `'' + yourdatecolumn LIKE '2010' –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was my own foolishness. There was another class filtering the string before it went to the bindingsource.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lack of [`documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) how to filter a `BindingSource` (or DataTable, DataView etc) by time instead of by Date only.

But this format should work:

```
"AND NextWorkDate <= #yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss#"
```

You can get this format by `DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

```
string filter = string.Format("...AND NextWorkDate <= #{0}#",
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString(
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

However, i would prefer Linq since it is more readable, maintainable and more powerful. So you can filter the underlying list with linq. If you use a `DataTable` use `Linq-To-DataSet`, otherwise use `Linq-To-Sql` or `Linq-To-Entities` to query the datasource or `Linq-To-Objects` if it's just an in-memory list. Then you just have to reassign the `DataSource`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nope, Not working. The only filter format for the date that I've found to work is dd.M.yyyy. I've been banging my head against this wall for days.

Comment: @user2538011: Edited my answer. Try `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead. I have tested it with  `DataTable.Select` which uses the same methods.

Comment: Still not working. BindingSourceFilter is a property of a custom datagridview. The datasource of the datagridview is a list of rows from the database. Hope I'm not doing something horribly wrong here.